# Re-export Shared Library Symbols from Other Library (OS X / POSIX)

Tags: c, macos, linker, shared-libraries, x86-64

*My question is fairly OS X on x86-64 specific but a universal solution that works on other POSIX OSes is even more appreciated.*

Given a list of symbol names of some shared library (called original library in the following) and I want my shared library to re-export these symbols. Re-export as in if someone tries to resolve the symbol against my library I either provide my version of this symbol or (if my library doesn't have this symbol) forward to the original library's symbol.

I don't know the types of the symbols, I only know whether they are functions (type `T` in `nm` output) or other symbols (type `S` in `nm` output).

For functions, I already have a solution: For every function I want to re-export I generate an assembly stub that does dynamically resolve the symbol (using `dlsym()`) and then jumps into the resolved function with the very same environment (registers `rdi`, `rsi`, `rdx`, `rcx`, `r8`, `r9`, stack pointer, ...). I'm basically generating universal proxy functions. Using some macro trickery that can be generated fairly easy without writing code for each and every symbol.

For non-function symbols the problem seems to be harder because I cannot generate this universal proxy function, because the resolving party does never call a function.

Using a constructor function `static void init(void) __attribute__((constructor));` I can execute code whenever someone loads my library, that would be a good point to resolve and re-export all non-function symbols if that's possible.

In other words, I'd like to write the symbol table of my library to point to the respective symbols of another shared library. Doing the rewriting at compile or run time is okay (run time preferred). Or put yet another way, the behaviour of `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` (`LD_PRELOAD`) is exactly what I need but I don't want to insert a new library, I want to replace one (in the file system). **EDIT**: The reason I don't want/can't use `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` or any other environment variable of the `DYLD_*` family is that they are ignored for code signed, restricted, ... binaries.

I'm aware of the `-reexport-l`, `-reexport_library` and `-reexported_symbols_list` linker flags but I could not get them to work, especially when my library is a "replacement" for frameworks that are part of umbrella frameworks (example: `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/SearchKit`) because `ld` forbids to link directly against parts of umbrella frameworks.

*EDIT:* Because I explained it somewhat ambiguously: I can't change the way the actual program is linked. The goal is to produce a shared library that is a replacement for the original library. (Apparently called *filter library*.)

Comment: Why not use LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Have your library in a separate path and have it as the first element in the path,this way your library would override the other one

Comment: Because on OS X all `DYLD_*` environment variables are ignored for code signed binaries, for restricted binaries and so forth. I do actually want to replace the library in the file system (as root) but I don't want/can't change all the programs linking against that library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it out now (OS X specific): `clang -o replacement-lib.dylib ... -Xlinker -reexport_library PATH_TO_ORIGINAL_LIB` does the trick. `PATH_TO_ORIGINAL_LIB` could for example be `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Versions/Current/SearchKit`.

If `PATH_TO_ORIGINAL_LIB` is a library that is part of an umbrella framework (as in the example above), then replace `PATH_TO_ORIGINAL_LIB` by the path of some other lib (I created a lib `empty.dylib` for that) and as a second step do

```
install_name_tool -change /usr/local/lib/empty.dylib PATH_TO_ORIGINAL_LIB replacement-lib.dylib
```

To see if the actual reexporting worked use:

```
otool -l replacement-lib.dylib | grep -A2 LC_REEXPORT_DYLIB
```

The output should look like

```
  cmd LC_REEXPORT_DYLIB
  cmdsize XX
     name empty.dylib (offset YY)
```

After launching the `install_name_tool` it could be

```
      cmd LC_REEXPORT_DYLIB
  cmdsize XX
     name /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Versions/Current/SearchKit (offset YY)
```

Comment: could you please hint how to do this  in Xcode? I am trying to package several google boost dylibs as a single framework and can't. I linked my (empty) framework against the boost dylibs, and I copy them into my framework, and I specified @executalbe_path for the framework, but my executable doesn't find any of the symbols in the boost dylibs. Idea?

Comment: I am sorry, but on Xcode 7, I get an error -reexport_library unknown argument.

Comment: You need the -Xlinker argument befire the -reexport_library one as it's a linker flag. I use this with Xcode 7 and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could link against both libraries and use the link order to make sure to link against the right symbols. This works on both OS X and Linux:

```
cc -o executable -lmylib -loriglib
```

Where `origlib` is the original library and `mylib` contains symbols that are supposed to overwrite symbols in `origlib`. Then the executable will be linked against your symbols from `mylib` first and all unresolved symbols will be linked against `origlib`.

This works in the same way when linking against OS X frameworks. Just link against your library that replaces symbols first and against the framework after.

```
cc -o executable -lmylib -framework SomeFramework
```

**Edit:** If you just want to replace symbols at runtime then you can use `LD_PRELOAD` in the same way:

```
cc -o executable -framework SomeFramework
LD_PRELOAD=libmylib.dylib ./executable
```

Comment: Sorry, I probably wrote quite ambiguously: I can't change how `executable` is linked. Ie: It's `cc -o executable -framework SomeFramework`. I now want to replace `SomeFramework` by my own version and "fall back" to the original `SomeFramework` library for every symbol I do not define. (edited my answer to reflect that)

Comment: @JohannesWeiß Why don't you use `LD_PRELOAD` in that case? Edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: yes, I know about `LD_PRELOAD` (or `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` on OS X) but I do want to achieve the same by replacing the library on the filesystem without using `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES`. The reason is that `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` is not taken into account for code signed binaries, for restricted binaries, ...