# Making a shared library that "re-exports" symbols from other shared libraries

Tags: interface, linker, dependencies, shared-libraries, elf

Suppose that there is a simple binary that depends on three libraries, `libA.so`, `libB.so`, and `libC.so`. In the usual case, these three dependencies would show up in `readelf` as needed. However, I am curious about whether it is possible to make a shared library `libABC.so` that does absolutely nothing but act as an interface to the three actual libraries by "redirecting" the symbols. This way, perhaps one can have multiple versions of `libABC.so` that in turn point to different versions of the three dependencies, and the binary can "depend" on just `libABC.so`. Is this possible with ELF?

Another possible use case is the inverse, when the binary already depends on an existing library `libABC.so` that just so happens to have become split up into three individual libraries.

Beware that I do not necessarily have a practical use or actual use case for this. Whether or not the above example cases are practical, I am merely curious about the possibility.

[Re-export Shared Library Symbols from Other Library (OS X / POSIX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20020715/re-export-shared-library-symbols-from-other-library-os-x-posix) has a promising title, but the answers seem either Darwin-specific, or do not quite answer this question.

Answer (score 4):

That *kind of* works with ELF because of the flat namespace of symbols: if you're depending on one library you usually get access to the symbols of its dependencies at the same time (the exception being when `dlopen()` is used).

But most link editors (`ld`) do not do that by default (anymore), because it would let unneeded libraries to be added to the dependencies otherwise. In GNU `ld` the feature is controlled by the `--as-needed` flag, and was turned on around 10 years ago by default if I remember correctly.

You should be able to force the behaviour you're looking into with GNU `ld` by linking (e.g. via the GCC frontend) with `gcc yourprogram.c -Wl,--no-as-needed -lABC -Wl,--as-needed`. That will force linking to `libABC.so` whether the program is using one of its exported symbols or not.

I have written extensively on the feature, because it solved many problems for distributions at the time, [on my blog](https://flameeyes.blog/tag/as-needed/) if you're looking into what the practicalities of it are.